# Reopen PendingIntent after AppDestroy

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent, activity-lifecycle

I have a problem with PendingIntent in my App.

I send GCM messages from my Server to my application. When the User clicks on the notification, a new PendingIntent will be created which moves the User to the "AlertActivity", where a countdown starts

All of this works fine at the moment.

The problem is now, when the user closes the app and reopen it.
While the Countdown is running i want to redirect the User to the AlertActivity again.

How is this possible?

I start the Intent with:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AlertActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Alert")
                .setContentText("You've received new message.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
        int defaults = 0;
        //defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        //defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        Notification notification = mNotifyBuilder.build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        // Set the content for Notification
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New message from Server");
        // Set autocancel
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Post a notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this completely, but what if you set your Main Activity to `singleTask`. Then, create a [back stack](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html#DirectEntry) that has Main Activity as the parent activity. From what I understand, this should preserve the navigation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried it but when i reopen the app, it still jumps to the MainActivity not to the AlertAcritivy